# What cheat sheets exist for Django?

Tags: django

What [cheat sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_sheet) exist for Django?

If possible, provide a description (e.g. scope, Django version information, number of pages, authors, direct download URL if it is in PDF), how you discovered it, etc.

Some external resources are [Our Favorite Cheat Sheets](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/0,,sid9_gci826135,00.html), [devcheatsheet.com](http://devcheatsheet.com/) and [TechPosters.NET](http://techposters.net/search/topics/?q=django), but I think there should be a directory for the Django cheat sheets here.

Answer (score 10):

Mercurytide [Django Cheat Sheet for Django 1.5](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-15-cheat-sheet/)
by Andrew Durdin and Henry Kunz.

It covers model fields (e.g. BooleanField, CharField, FloatField, etc.), template tags, template filters, template date formats, and many others. 2 pages.

[Direct link](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/media/resources/django-cheat-sheet.pdf) (PDF format, 73 KB). [older - Greyscale version](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/media/whitepapers/django-cheat-sheet/django10-cheat-sheet-grayscale.pdf). The greyscale version prints a little bit better on a black-and-white printer, but not much. This cheat sheet is much better suited for a colour printer.

Answer (score 5):

For Django 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5, check [Django 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5 cheat sheets](http://www.revsys.com/django/cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 2):

*[Django 1.4 Cheatsheet](http://djangolinks.com/detail/django-14-cheatsheet-67/)* might help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Django 1.5 cheat sheet from Mercurytide. http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-15-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

Why settle for only one language or framework when you can have many: [DevCheatSheet](http://devcheatsheet.com/).  It's a cheat sheet agregator website.

Comment: There are three (http://devcheatsheet.com/tag/django/), although one's outdated and the other one's the Mercurytide sheet.

Comment: Also, nice symmetry... devcheatsheet.com uses Django underneath!

Answer (score 0):

There is a iPhone version which I found is useful.

http://appshopper.com/productivity/django-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Updated Django 1.5 cheat sheet can be found here [Django Cheatsheets](http://www.revsys.com/django/cheatsheet/)